# Check if file is uploaded or not

Tags: jquery, validation, file-upload

I have form which is having simple file upload field:

```
<input type="file" name="resume" id="resume">
```

I want to check  whether user has select file or not  using `jQuery`.

```
$('#careerform').submit(function()
{
        var error = 0;      

var is_upload = 0;

$("#resume").on("change",function(event) 
{         
     is_upload = 1;
     error = 0;
});


if(is_upload == 0)
{
    alert('Please upload your resume');
    error = 1;  
    return false;

}

});
```

**What is the problem :**

Scenario 1 : User has not select any file and click the submit button it shows error "Please upload your resume". (Which is correct)

Scenario 2 : After alerting the message, now if user has select the file it again throws an alert "Please upload your resume". (Not correct)

Comment: It throws the message again? From the code you show that is not possible. It should only alert once.

Comment: yes it give the alert again

Comment: That is not possible. The `if (is_upload == 0) ... ` bit is only executed once. So is the `alert`. Is this all your code?

Comment: I think he did not post his whole script.

Comment: @putvande see http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmarty/a5Tn6/

Comment: `var is_upload == 0;` should be `var is_upload = 0;`

Comment: @VivekParekh it was typo i have corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables `is_upload` and `error` should be outside your submit function. In your code they are reset to `0` everytime you submit, no mather if you have uploaded something.

And your `change` event should also be outside that. It makes no sense to put it inside the submit function.
And defining variables should be with 1 `=` instead of 2.

```
var is_upload = 0;
var error = 0;

$("#resume").on("change", function (event) {
    is_upload = 1;
    error = 0;
});

$('#myform').submit(function () {

    if (is_upload == 0) {
        alert('Please upload your resume');
        error = 1;
        return false;

    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5Tn6/2/

Comment: thanks it works. and the variable declaration part `=` it was the typo so i have corrected in my question